# Tikz nodes moves after double building

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, overlays, groupplots, remember

I want to plot 4 graphs in one tikzpicture in a 2x2 grid, using groupplot. Also I want to put some arrows from nodes in the first three plots to nodes in the last one. To do this, I try to use `remember picture` and `overlay`, but probably I set it incorrectly.

When I build the output, after one compilation I got the plots and arrows correctly, but if I compile twice, the arrows move to some other coordinates. In addition, if I make some changes, for example in the nodes coordinates, with just a compilation the output is not updated, but I have to delete the temporary files created during the building process and then compile.

Why is this happening? I'd like to avoid this manual deletion process and to get the arrows right after multiple compilations.

Here's the MWE. Probably some packages are useless/redundant.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % in order to use color names
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfsys,pgffor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,mindmap,calc,through,scopes,fadings,positioning,automata,calendar,shapes,er,matrix,folding,patterns,petri,plothandlers,plotmarks,shadows,topaths,through,trees,pgfplots.units,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,positioning} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,units}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\begin{groupplot}[
        /pgfplots/group/horizontal sep=1.75cm,
        /pgfplots/group/vertical sep=1cm,
    group style={
                group size=2 by 2},
                yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/precision=3},
                xlabel=$\tau$,
        axis y line=left,
                axis x line=bottom,
                xlabel style={below},height=4cm, width=4cm
        ]
\nextgroupplot[remember picture,line width=1pt, ylabel=$\lambda_1$, ylabel style={rotate=-90},ymin=0.9,ymax=1.5]
\addplot[line width=1pt,no markers,cyan] function{x};
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (axis cs:0.1,0.9) -- (axis cs:0.1,1.19449) node (y1) {};
%
\nextgroupplot[remember picture,line width=1pt, ylabel=$t_1$, ylabel style={rotate=-90},ymin=-0.7,ymax=0.1]
\addplot[line width=1pt,no markers,cyan,domain=-0.7:0.1] function{-2*x};
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (axis cs:0.1,-0.7) -- (axis cs:0.1,-0.212258) node (t1) {};
%
\nextgroupplot[remember picture,line width=1pt, ylabel=$\lambda_2$, ylabel style={rotate=-90},ymin=1.35,ymax=1.75]
\addplot[line width=1pt,no markers,cyan] function{x};
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (axis cs:0.1,1.35) -- (axis cs:1,1.39089)  node (y2) {};
%
\nextgroupplot[name=step,remember picture,line width=1pt, ylabel=$\lambda(t)$, xlabel=$t$,xtick={-0.6,-0.3,0}, ylabel style={rotate=-90},xmin=-0.8,xmax=0.1,ymin=0.9,ymax=1.75] 
\draw[cyan, solid] (axis cs:-0.8,1.19449) -- (axis cs:-0.212258,1.19449) -- (axis cs:-0.212258,1.39089) -- (axis cs:0,1.39089);
\node[draw, line width=0.5pt] at (axis cs:-0.3,1.6) {$\tau=0.1$};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (y1end) at (axis cs:-0.5,1.19449) {};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (y2end) at (axis cs:-0.212258,1.39089) {};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (t1end) at (axis cs:-0.212258,1.2) {};
\end{groupplot}

\draw[->] (y1) .. controls +(-20:1) and +(120:1) ..  (y1end);
\draw[->] (y2) .. controls +(80:1.5) and +(160:2) .. (y2end);
\draw[->] (t1) .. controls +(-20:2) and +(15:2)  ..  (t1end);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your commands for `addplot` wasn't quite right. Just remove the word `function` and add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}` should get you right on the track.

Comment: As you are within the same tikzpicture there's no need to use the options `remember picture` and `overlay`.

Comment: You are right ClaudioFiandrino, without those keys it works correctly! Post it as an answer (or I'll do).

Comment: @Nicola, do you still plan to do a self-answer?

Answer (score 2):

As ClaudioFiandrino suggested, without the keys `remember picture` and `overlay` the code works.

Here's the (almost) MWE (probably some packages is useless or redundat).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfsys,pgffor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,mindmap,calc,through,scopes,fadings,positioning,automata,calendar,shapes,er,matrix,folding,patterns,petri,plothandlers,plotmarks,shadows,topaths,through,trees,pgfplots.units,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,positioning} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,units}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
        /pgfplots/group/horizontal sep=1.75cm,
        /pgfplots/group/vertical sep=1cm,
    group style={
                group size=2 by 2},
                yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/precision=3},
                xlabel=$\tau$,
        axis y line=left,
                axis x line=bottom,
                xlabel style={below},height=4cm, width=4cm,
        ]
\nextgroupplot[line width=1pt, ylabel=$\lambda_1$, ylabel style={rotate=-90},ymin=0.9,ymax=1.5]
\addplot[line width=1pt,no markers,cyan] function{x};
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (axis cs:0.1,0.9) -- (axis cs:0.1,1.19449) node (y1) {};
%
\nextgroupplot[line width=1pt, ylabel=$t_1$, ylabel style={rotate=-90},ymin=-0.7,ymax=0.1]
\addplot[line width=1pt,no markers,cyan,domain=-0.7:0.1] function{-2*x};
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (axis cs:0.1,-0.7) -- (axis cs:0.1,-0.212258) node (t1) {};
%
\nextgroupplot[line width=1pt, ylabel=$\lambda_2$, ylabel style={rotate=-90},ymin=1.35,ymax=1.75]
\addplot[line width=1pt,no markers,cyan] function{x};
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (axis cs:2,1.35) -- (axis cs:2,1.39089)  node (y2) {};
%
\nextgroupplot[line width=1pt, ylabel=$\lambda(t)$, xlabel=$t$,xtick={-0.6,-0.3,0}, ylabel style={rotate=-90},xmin=-0.8,xmax=0.1,ymin=0.9,ymax=1.75] 
\draw[cyan, solid] (axis cs:-0.8,1.19449) -- (axis cs:-0.212258,1.19449) -- (axis cs:-0.212258,1.39089) -- (axis cs:0,1.39089);
\node[draw, line width=0.5pt] at (axis cs:-0.3,1.6) {$\tau=0.1$};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (y1end) at (axis cs:-0.5,1.19449) {};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (y2end) at (axis cs:-0.212258,1.39089) {};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (t1end) at (axis cs:-0.212258,1.2) {};
\end{groupplot}
\draw[->] (y1) .. controls +(-20:1) and +(120:1) ..  (y1end);
\draw[->] (y2) .. controls +(80:1.5) and +(160:2) .. (y2end);
\draw[->] (t1) .. controls +(-20:2) and +(15:2)  ..  (t1end);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here's a png version of the output.
[image]